# Undefined control sequence with ntheorem and shaded theorems

Tags: theorems, ntheorem, newtheorem

I am working with ntheorem and have the following definition of a shaded theorem:

```
\theoremclass{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{break}
\shadecolor{red}
\def\theoremframecommand{%
\psshadowbox[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=cyan,linecolor=black]}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\diamondsuit}}
\newshadedtheorem{sthm}{Theorem}[section]
```

but everytimeI compile I get the error:

```
undefined control sequence
```

where I have:

```
begin{sthm}
```

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm,right=2.00cm,top=2.45cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amscd,color,enumitem,epsfig}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,framed,latexsym,multicol,pstricks,slashed,xcolor}
\usepackage[amsmath,framed,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setcounter{chapter}{-1}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}{}}
\lhead{\leftmark}
\rhead{\rightmark}
\cfoot{\thepage}

\theoremstyle{marginbreak}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries}\theorembodyfont{\slshape}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\diamondsuit}}
\theoremseparator{:}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\theoremclass{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{break}
\shadecolor{red}
\def\theoremframecommand{%
\psshadowbox[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=cyan,linecolor=black]}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\diamondsuit}}
\newshadedtheorem{sthm}{Theorem}[section]

\title{Calculus Notes}
\author{}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\chapter{Limits}
\begin{sthm}[Basic Limits]

\end{sthm}

\end{document}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

-MD

Comment: unrelated but don't use `epsfig` package unless you really need to emulate a document from before 1993.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not show the full error message, which shows which command is undefined:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \c@lor@to@ps
```

That is a well known failure caused by using pstricks with `pdflatex` instead of `latex`.

If you process the document with `latex` there is no error.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to add to my MWE the following in the preamble:                      \theoremclass{Theorem}
    \theoremstyle{break}
    \newshadedtheorem{prop}[Theorem]{Proposition}                                                  but when I did I got the error                                                                                         No counter "theorem" defined. How can I adress that? Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I also tried the exact coding used in ntheorem manual:                        \theoremclass{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{break}
\theoreminframepreskip{0pt}
\theoreminframepostskip{0pt}
\theoremframepreskip{1cm}
\theoremframepostskip{1cm}
\theoremstyle{break}
\def\theoremframecommand{%
\psshadowbox[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue,linecolor=black]}
\newshadedtheorem{sthm}[Theorem]{Theorem}                                                 and that still produced the error:                                                                           no counter "theorem" defined.

Comment: @MichaelDykes best to ask new questions as new questions, as you found, comments don't really work for code blocks.

Comment: You still can compile with `pdflatex` if you load `auto-pst-pdf` at the end of your preamble, and launch it with the `-shell-escape` switch.